# Embed Yii module page in Facebook app

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, yii, integration

I've created Yii quiz module which I also want to use in Facebook app (Facebook side).
It can be done trough iframe, but generated page have got also menus and many other unnecessary (in this case) stuff. Is it possible in Yii to show only generated module code without rest of the website?

Comment: just use a different layout for that module, have you tried that already?

Comment: No, but that sounds interesting. Can You give me more tips how to do that?

Comment: ok, lemme expand that into an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try and use a different layout for that module. First you can add a layout folder and layout files to that module, say : */protected/modules/quiz/views/layouts/quizlayout.php*. So this new *quizlayout.php* should be your layout for all the views in this module.

To do that you can set the [`layout` property](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CWebModule#layout-detail) of the *quizmodule* in the QuizModule class's `init()`, like so (in *QuizModule.php*):

```
class QuizModule extends CWebModule {

    public function init() {
        // this method is called when the module is being created
        // you may place code here to customize the module or the application

        // import the module-level models and components
        $this->setImport(array(
            'quiz.models.*',
            'quiz.components.*',
        ));
        $this->layout='quizlayout';
    }

    //...
}
```

Now by default, gii generated modules' controllers are subclasses of the `Controller` class in *component/Controller.php* file. And that `Controller` class defines a `layout`, so if you have that same structure, then the above method will not work, and you'll have to override the layout within your modules' controllers. However instead of going inside each controller and adding a line, you can instead do this in the `beforeControllerAction($controller, $action)` function in *QuizModule.php* :

```
public function beforeControllerAction($controller, $action) {

    if(parent::beforeControllerAction($controller, $action)) {
        // this method is called before any module controller action is performed
        // you may place customized code here

        $controller->layout='quizlayout';

        return true;
    }
    else
        return false;
}
```

**Edit:**

Of course your *quizlayout.php* should not have code for menus, and any extra stuff, but at the very least the `echo $content` line should be there, as also mentioned in eskimo's answer.

Answer (score 1):

In you protected/views there is a file called "main.php"
This is your main layout file, that gets rendered around any view called by $this->render

To remove the menu etc.. remove everything within the body except for the line:

```
<?php echo $content; ?>
```

Obviously leave in all the stuff in the head (.css files etc...)